# Laravel: Accessing Output Instance In Job

Tags: laravel, command, queue

I would like to know the best way to access and/or pass the output instance of a command to a queued job instance. All I want to do is be able to output info to the command line while my job is running from a working queue. It doesn't seem like there is any easy way to do so unless I'm missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i personally do this in this way:
in terminal open `tail -f storage/log/laravel.log` and in your job handler `\Log::info('output whatever i need');`

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I would like to send output directly to the terminal using the output instance in the command.

Comment: All indications seem to point to using the log. That is probably what I will end up doing. Thanks.

Comment: If you please accept my answer I'll be greatfull. Thanks